# No output for N-Channel MOSFET on PWM on STM32F0

Tags: mosfet, stm32, pwm, mosfet-driver

I am using dual N-Channel MOSFET FS8205A, following is a screenshot from its [datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5a2d.png).
[image]

and the following is the schematic I am using in my project.

[image]

The Gate is also pulled down to the ground with a 10K resistor, but the problem is, I am not getting any output, I have even replaced the microcontroller, and the same issue, I think the problem is somewhere is in the design of MOSFET circuit that I can not figure out, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hard to say anything without seeing how the mosfet is connected to the rest of the circuit. BTW, the pins D1 and D2 are internally connected to each other, so why do you have two  different labels, R and G?

Comment: @vtolentino thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a dual MOSFET designed for battery protection, not really for general-purpose use because the drains are **connected together internally**.

When PA4 **or** PA6 is high then 'R' and 'G' should show continuity to ground (they are connected together internally.

When PA7 is high, then 'B' should show continuity to ground.

If you were, say, to connect an LED to a supply through a resistor to each of 'R', 'G', and 'B', then 'R' and 'G' would go off and on together.